# Batch '+ unexpected' error

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I'm trying to code a collatz conjecture tester in batch (it's math stuff). The point of the file is to test whether a number is even, and if it is divide by two. If the number is odd, it's supposed to multiply by three and add one. This should loop over and over. Every time I try and run this file, it allows me to input the number, then it says '+ was unexpected at this time.' What is my error here?

```
@echo off
color f0
title Collatz Conjecture Tester
echo/
echo Enter the number you want to test.
echo/
echo/
set /p number=
:start
set /a test=%number% %% 2
if %test% EQU 0 ( 
    set /a number=%number% * 1/2
) else (
    set /a number=(%number% * 3) + 1
)
echo/
echo Result: %number%
timeout /t 1 >nul
goto start
```

Comment: It's worth noting that all numbers in batch are signed 32-bit integers, so the largest input your code will accept is 2147483647, and even then the `3n+1` part of your code means there will be an integer overflow and the result will go negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862) already found the root cause of the problem and showed a proper solution in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439763).

An alternative way to avoid trouble with parentheses and also some operators like `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, etc. is to enclose the entire expression of `set /A` within a pair of quotation marks:

```
if %test% EQU 0 ( 
    set /A "number=%number% * 1/2"
) else (
    set /A "number=(%number% * 3) + 1"
)
```

If you do that consequently, you do not have to think of proper escaping any more.

Note that the `%` operator always needs to be escaped like `%%` in a batch file.
In [case delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, the `!` operator needs to be escaped like `^!` in case the expression is placed within `""`, and by `^^!` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

When you have parentheses inside of `if` statements, `for` loops, or other code blocks, it's important that you escape any other inner closing parentheses so that the batch interpreter knows you aren't done yet.

Right now, batch is reading your `if` statement like this:

```
else (
    set /a number=(%number% * 3
)
+ 1
```

And so it thinks you're terminating the `else` early and throwing a `+ 1` in there for some reason. To get around this, you can escape the inner close parenthesis with a `^`.

```
if %test% EQU 0 ( 
    set /a number=%number% * 1/2
) else (
    set /a number=(%number% * 3^) + 1
)
```